# Why are there three comparisons to add a second map element?

Tags: c++, insert, stdmap

When I run the following code (with a line commented out) I get no output (no comparisons are made).
But the moment I uncomment the last line I get three lines of output (three comparisons are made). When a second item is added, 1-2 comparisons is understandable, but why a third?

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyType
{
  public :
  int a;
  MyType():a(0){}
};

bool operator<(const MyType &lhs, const MyType &rhs)
{
  cout<<"operator < is called\n";
  return lhs.a < rhs.a;
}

int main()
{
  MyType T1,T2;
  T1.a = 100;
  T2.a = 33; 
  
  map<MyType,int> Test;

  Test[T1] = 10; 
  //Test[T2] = 20; --> #Uncomment this line for getting 3 lines of "operator < is called"

}
```

The output with the line uncommented:

```
operator < is called
operator < is called
operator < is called
```

How did it end up in printing three strings from zero with just one extra key got added?

[MyCodeOnline](https://onlinegdb.com/e3Uo2T8fQ)

Here are the addresses of `lhs` and `rhs`:

```
0x56365ea45e90
0x7ffe3c4cd47c
operator < is called
0x7ffe3c4cd47c
0x56365ea45e90
operator < is called
0x56365ea462d0
0x56365ea45e90
operator < is called
```

Comment: It's like plugging in a USB device.  Try it the first way and it fails, try it the second way and it fails, try it the first way again and it plugs in.

Comment: When you add the first item to a map, it's empty and there's nothing to compare to.

Comment: On my system (clang-cl) the `<` operator is called twice. I suppose it's implementation-defined how to implement the `std::map` container and its operators.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yes, but when second item was added 1-2 comparison was ok , but why third?

Comment: @AdrianMole the constraints on `std::map` properties tend to lead to all implementations using very similar structures and algorithms.

Comment: You might gain some insight if you had your debug output include the address of `lhs` and `rhs`.

Comment: @AdrianMole: Just added my code in online to make sure that issue is reproducible.

Comment: You could also take a look at the source code of whatever standard library implementation your are using. Maybe you can even use your debugger to step through library code. This is an implementation detail and not defined by the standard.

Comment: @churill: ok...

Comment: @MarkRansom: Updated with address as well in description.

Comment: Evidently the first two comparisons establish that `T2` does not equal the key in the map (a copy of `T1`), and the third comparison is between the copies of `T2` and `T1` that serve as keys in the map. I don't have an explanation for why that third comparison was deemed necessary though.

Comment: It seems to me that this has more to do with maps than operator overloading. There would have been three comparisons without the overload -- you just had no way to count the comparisons.

Comment: Interestingly, note that using `emplace` instead of `operator[]` will only invoke `operator<` twice - suggests that the third use might come from the copies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a visual studio debug build it generates a lot of extra code in the standard library to catch various bugs.

In the case of `std::map` after inserting a new value it checks that the comparator correctly returns false for `comp(key, key)` and therefore implements the required strict weak ordering.

If you switch to a release build there are only 2 comparisons as you'd expect.

I presume what's happening in libstdc++ is that `Test[T2] = 20` has to perform four operations:

1. Check whether `T2` already exists
2. Insert a new element for `T2`
3. Return a reference to the new element
4. Assign the value of the new element to `20`

I'm guessing libstdc++ hasn't optimised step 1 and 2 to reuse the comparisons. If you use `insert` to insert elements into the map only 2 comparisons are performed (this should be more efficient in all standard libraries even if they manage to not generate extra calls to the comparator):

```
Test.insert(std::make_pair(T2, 20));
```

Comment: which version of gcc?

Comment: gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)

Comment: It's no difference with g++ 11.1.0: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bd9db4eaaae0a4c)

Comment: Using the spaceship instead doesn't change things as well: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef3e78075b4ca945). I just tried it out of curiosity...

Comment: @AlanBirtles In fact: With `std::insert()` it's one less: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d058fec2fa029d8)

Comment: Yes, 2 as I said?

Answer (score 1):

I'm basing this answer on the libstdc++ gcc implementation of a map which uses a RB tree as the underlying storage.

When using `operator[]` to insert in to a map, it will do two things: First, it will see if it can find the existing element in the map and secondly will add/update the element to the new value.

1. The find operation is the first use of `operator<`
2. The next use is when inserting in to the underlying RB tree. Again, the first operation is to check to see whether the new node value is equal to the node already in the tree.
3. The second operation, is then where to place the new node relative to the previous node.

This is in contrast to the map `emplace` or `insert` operations, which will not do the `find` operation and will skip straight to inserting the node in to the underlying tree.